# Executing Shell Scripts from Java, Shell scripts having read operation

Tags: java, bash, shell

I have a Shell Scripts that read the Input

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"
read year
echo $year
```

I'm executing this shell scripts using JAVA APi

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "/junk/leaptest.sh");
final Process process = pb.start();

InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;


while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);       
}
System.out.println("Program terminated!");
```

In the Java Console I can see the Output

> Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:

Now the Actual Problem in How to pass the values to the Shell Scripts  in my scripts how the varialble "year" can be read

---

I have edited the code as per the suggestion but doesn't work where we correct it

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "/junk/leaptest.sh");
final Process process = pb.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
/*
 * OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream(); PrintWriter pw = new
 * PrintWriter(os);
 */

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
    // pw.println("8999");
    bw.write("2012");
}
System.out.println("Program terminated!");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass values from java program that executes script to the script use command line arguments. If you want to send information back from script to java program print the value in script, read the script's STDOUT in java program and parse it.

You really almost there. Now you are reading the script output (into while loop) but you are just printing it. Parse the output and do what you need with it.

Comment: thanks Alexr parse the Output means what ? how to acieve this

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `OutputStream` of the `Process` class:

```
OutputStream os = process.getOutputStream();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os);

pw.println("1997");
```

What you write to this output stream will become the input stream of the shell script. So `read year` will read 1987 to the `year` variable.

**EDIT:**

I also tried it out and I've managed to find the problem. The 1997 string hasn't reached the script, beacuse `PrintWriter` buffers the data that was written to it. You either have to flush the `PrintWriter` stream after the `println()` with `pw.flush()` or you have to set the auto-flush property to `true` upon creation:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os, true);
```

Here is the complete code that was working fine for me:

*leaptest.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"
read year
echo $year
```

*Test.java:*

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "leaptest.sh");
            final Process process = pb.start();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                pw.println("1997");
                pw.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("Program terminated!");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*Output:*

```
$ java Test
Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:
1997
Program terminated!
```

Comment: thanks buc any live code want to share, i;m missing that part

Comment: @anish: I've found the error and updated my answer with a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Think you should parse input stream is to extract your values. Parse it by lines.

Comment: thanks alexey , how to parse input stream, can u guide me on this

Answer (score 1):

You want to set up an OutputStream using [getOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) aswell, to be able to write data from your Java program into the process.

> public abstract OutputStream getOutputStream()
>
> Gets the output stream of the subprocess. Output to the stream is piped into the standard input stream of the process represented by
>   this Process object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. You need to handle your subprocess' output stream. Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29).

```
 BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream()));
 bw.write("2012");
```