# Java ProcessBuilder using authentication

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am  executing an external application using java process builder.

for eg

```
./appl -file user@host:/tmp/out.log
```

This application first retrieves the file `out.log` from the external host and then executes.
Also, once the above command prompt is executed, it prompts for the host password.

How do I achieve this using java process builder?
I tried to enter the command in the below mentioned way. However it throws an error that host is not found.

```
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("./appl");
command.add("-file");
command.add("user@host:/tmp/out.log");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have explicitly mentioned:
*Also, once the above command prompt is executed, it prompts for the host password.*

I believe the reason that the command is not being executed because the sub-process that you have triggered needs an input(host password),which you are not providing. Hence, you need to make an `OutputStream` to provide an input to your sub-process. For starters, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810943/executing-shell-scripts-from-java-shell-scipts-having-read-operation/10811038#10811038).

Comment: I tried to do this, however it does not seem to work. I am currently starting a new thread which reads the output generated by the external application. The java program just hangs.Is there any working example