# How can I print the output of a shell script to my html page?

Tags: html, printing, echo

I'm working with a tomcat server, javascript, and a .java & a .vm file. All the html is in the .vm file and all these files are connected. The reason in stating these facts is to show that if there is a Java solution in how to do my queried task, then please help with that as well =]

So..
I already have my web page executing the .sh file from my desktop which, for now,  only prints :

> Hello New World!..

to a .txt file on my desktop. What I want to do is also have that output show up on my web page immediately after I click the "Execute" button.

and i don't want to use php

Any pointers? Solutions? please. =]

Comment: Maybe this is helpful as the answers explain a way to send values to a shell script and also to get the output back: "[Executing Shell Scripts from Java, Shell scipts having read operation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10810943/1456376)"